# How do i extract the ip address from text file

Tags: c, string, ip

I want a program to extract the IP addresses from a text file "rawdata.txt" containing raw traceroute data of popular websites as shown below.

```
Tracing route to www.google.com [173.194.38.145]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1

Tracing route to ds-sg-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com [106.10.187.79]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

Trace complete.
```

Comment: You need to write script to do this (shell, perl script etc). Why are you trying it in C ?

Comment: Stev, it is perfectly doable in C too. Maybe the files are huge and he needs some performance which C surely offers.

Comment: I am working on a C project in which i have to implement this.

Comment: Can you help me kelm in writing this code?

Comment: Kelm, yes I agree it is doable in C. But this kind of problems can be easily solved with simple scripts and linux commands. He can call that script in C too.

Comment: This is my code http://pastebin.com/TccdWAQR

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small program in C that will read bytes from stdin and look for the following pattern:

```
%d.%d.%d.%d\n
```

... once it finds this pattern it will store the IP address respectively and continue searching. You would need to pipe your text file to the program:

```
./program < textfile.txt
```

Comment: Won't work when the IP is also resolved to hostname. In such case you need to look for either `%d.%d.%d.%d\n` or `[%d.%d.%d.%d]\n`.

Comment: The tracert data is already stored in the file. I want to read this file and extract ip address string from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file line by line and concatenate each line by `' '` delimiter. Then you need to check if 5th token is an IP address (only numbers and dots). If not, take it from the 6th token.

If you are writing a multi-threaded application the usage of strtok is discouraged. You can either write your own tokenizer or you sscanf.